# Does offering a firstborn male child to God strip him of the sovereignty and thus inheritance of land?

Tags: law, deuteronomy, numbers, sacrifice

My question refers to the totality of biblical domain as I suspect this rule/law was in effect even before Abraham. If it indeed existed it would be a corollary of to the rule of the first born inheriting the land that has manifested in Japhet/Sim but even earlier in Kain/Abel.

Yet the most interesting practical application to the hermeneutics would be to the wholeburnt offering of Isaak to god Genesis, 22:1-10.

The Isaak was brought to the site without being informed of himself to be sacrificed, bound and put on the pile of wood to be killed and burned to ashes. He then was exchanged for a ram instead. The ram that was killed and burned. What we see is the complete reduction of a human to a mute animal.  Otherwise a sovereign human being and a lawful heir to a powerful father is stripped of all his rights and is not informed/consulted. Then he is substituted and one can argue bought back for a ram. This could be seen as his worth equated to the one of a stray ram immobilized himself entangled in a bush.

If we put aside the Abraham's dilemma of getting the Isaak due to the act of god and thus having to give him back on demand, what happens to the Isaak standing in the world and in the family?

If not an actual process of striping the formal sovereignty, wasn't the above at least a manifestation of Isaak having lost it's sovereignty and (at least some of) inheritance right?

Later the Levites were left without any land in Israel:

> 1 The priests the Levites, and all the tribe of Levi, **shall have no**
> **part nor inheritance with Israel**: they shall eat the offerings of the
> LORD made by fire, and his inheritance. 2 Therefore shall they have no
> inheritance among their brethren: the LORD is their inheritance, as he
> hath said unto them.
> [Deuteronomy 18:1 KJV](https://biblehub.com/kjv/deuteronomy/18.htm)

> 11 And the LORD spake unto Moses, saying, 12 And I, behold, I have taken
> **the Levites from among the children of Israel instead of all the**
> **firstborn** that openeth the matrix among the children of Israel:
> therefore the Levites shall be mine; 13 Because all the firstborn are
> mine; for on the day that I smote all the firstborn in the land of
> Egypt I hallowed unto me all the firstborn in Israel, both man and
> beast: mine shall they be: I am the LORD. [Numbers 3 KJV](https://biblehub.com/kjv/numbers/3.htm)

So again, is there any hint in the bible as to what should happen to the sovereignty and inheritance rights of a firstborn offered to a god (and bought back) as a rule?

Answer (score 0):

Every firstborn son automatically belonged to God, and had to be redeemed by his parents.

> And every firstling of an ass thou shalt redeem with a lamb; and if
> thou wilt not redeem it, then thou shalt break his neck: and all the
> firstborn of man among thy children shalt thou redeem. (Exodus 13:13,
> KJV)
>
> But the firstling of an ass thou shalt redeem with a lamb: and if thou
> redeem him not, then shalt thou break his neck. All the firstborn of
> thy sons thou shalt redeem. And none shall appear before me empty.
> (Exodus 34:20, KJV)
>
> Every thing that openeth the matrix in all flesh, which they bring
> unto the LORD, whether it be of men or beasts, shall be thine:
> nevertheless the firstborn of man shalt thou surely redeem, and the
> firstling of unclean beasts shalt thou redeem. (Numbers 18:15, KJV)

The redemption price for the firstborn was not due until the child had survived his first month.

> And those that are to be redeemed from a month old shalt thou redeem,
> according to thine estimation, for the money of five shekels, after
> the shekel of the sanctuary, which is twenty gerahs. (Numbers 18:16,
> KJV)

Human sons were required to be redeemed, and the firstborn of unclean animals, which could not be offered to God in sacrifices, had to be redeemed.  The firstborn of clean animals, however, were not permitted to be redeemed--they were to be sacrificed.

> But the firstling of a cow, or the firstling of a sheep, or the
> firstling of a goat, thou shalt not redeem; they are holy: thou shalt
> sprinkle their blood upon the altar, and shalt burn their fat for an
> offering made by fire, for a sweet savor unto the LORD. (Numbers
> 18:17, KJV)

Abraham's case with Isaac was special.  God used it for two purposes simultaneously, in addition to providing *us* with valuable lessons.

1. God was testing Abraham's faithfulness following multiple times where he had lied to save his own life, claiming Sarah was just his sister, not his wife.  Had he learned his lesson?  The test of sparing his son's life would be more difficult to any father than to spare one's own life.
2. God was teaching Abraham about the future sacrifice of the Messiah, God's own son, and how much it meant that God would be willing to go through with this for undeserving sinners.  This experience would take Abraham to a whole new level of understanding of God's plan of redemption.

After Abraham had shown willingness to sacrifice his son Isaac, who was redeemed with the substitute of the ram, what happened to Isaac's birthright?  Nothing.  He still received the birthright promise.

God had promised that Isaac would receive His covenant blessing.

> And God said, Sarah thy wife shall bear thee a son indeed; and thou
> shalt call his name Isaac: and I will establish my covenant with him
> for an everlasting covenant, and with his seed after him. (Genesis
> 17:19, KJV)

And Abraham gave Isaac all of his property.  The children of the concubines did not receive Isaac's blessing, nor his inheritance.

> <sup>5</sup>And Abraham gave all that he had unto Isaac.
> <sup>6</sup>But unto the sons of the concubines, which Abraham had,
> Abraham gave gifts, and sent them away from Isaac his son, while he
> yet lived, eastward, unto the east country. (Genesis 25:5-6, KJV)

### Conclusion

Being a firstborn son, and being redeemed from being God's possession, does not nullify the firstborn's inheritance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yet Isaak himself did not receive any land that was promised to Abraham and Ismael descendants are arguably much more numerous than Israels. As we know only hundreds of years later Isaak descendants have entered the land of Israel and only after all firstborns (lawful heirs to the land of Canaan?) of Egypt were killed. And even then the Jews did not have full sovereignty over the land of Israel. To the Christians the promise was certainly not fulfilled on earth ("slaves do not inherit the land of the master, but children inherit from father").